# What does || do in console.log() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is a solution for FizzBuzz (it prints the numbers 1 to 100, but prints "Fizz" for numbers that are divisible by 3, "Buzz" for numbers divisible by 5, and "FizzBuzz" for numbers divisible by both).

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    var output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "Fizz";
    if (n % 5 == 0)
        output += "Buzz";
    console.log(output || n);
}
```

I don't understand how the `||` works in `console.log(output || n);`

Usually a boolean expression like that evaluates to either true or false.

Comment: This was at least the fourth question asking [JS logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in a short period. They don't return booleans, they return operands.

Comment: thanks that was very helpful

Comment: You're wellcome. Also, naturally `!` is not returning operand, it always returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The OR operator retuns the left side if it's truthy, if it's falsy retuns the right side. Same:

```
var foo = output || n;
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`""`, the empty string, is considered a "falsy" value in JavaScript. That is, when used in an expression involving boolean operators, `""` is treated as `false`. The MDN has a [resource on falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript.

For example, the code snippet `if ("") console.log("Hello, World!");` will not produce any output, as the `if` statement evaluates its expression to be `false`.

In the case of your solution to FizzBuzz, should `output` never have anything appended to it, the expression `output || n` will effectively be `false || n`, and due to the way JavaScript evaluates boolean operators, the expression will evaluate to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no output from the `if`'s, it's print the number (n). This is what `||` do here ;)